# Flutter - firestore for each user

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i've two users so my app has login/signup , so they when they sign in  they can add lists ,

so basically i've added the below code (rules)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when i sign in with another account , the data is showing , i mean this data is visible for all authenticated users , how i can make it every users has their own list and they can CRUD & no one can see another user data , i think you guys understand,  sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you run against these rules and that is not giving you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial which can answer your every question about firestore rules

https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e

Comment: **the rules are fine but how i can do that for this project , could you please take a look at it one minute :) ** [GITHUB](https://github.com/lohanidamodar/lender)